# Set parent width based on its children

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API to display things on a Map as they are added to the apps DB.  I am using `"google-map-react": "^0.25.0"` to interact with the Google Maps API.  And I am using React to render the map elements.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './renderMap.css'

export default class BathoomMarker extends Component {
  render() {
    let bathroomMarker_Name_Open = this.props.$hover ? 'bathroomMarker--name' : 'bathroomMarker--name__closed'

    return (
      <div className='bathroomMarker'>
        <div className='bathroomMarker--img'></div>
        <div className={bathroomMarker_Name_Open}>{ this.props.name }</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
.bathroomMarker {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.bathroomMarker--img {
  background-image: url('./toilet.png');
  background-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.bathroomMarker--name {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is, the `bathRoomMarker` is rendered in an anonymous div with a declared `width: 0;`.  Because of this, `bathRoomMarker` has to have a width declared.

I am looking for a way to set the width of `bathRoomMarker` dynamically based on the size of is children.

Is there a way to do that?